# how to change hash tag of links in jquery ui-tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have few jquery tabs for my docs e.g.

```
<div id="doc-tabs">
<ul id="doc-list">
<li><a  href="{{media_root}}api/api.html" >Introduction</a></li>
<li><a  href="{{media_root}}api/auth.html" >Authentication</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I convert them to tabs using jquery

```
$('#doc-tabs').tabs()
```

problem is jquery converts all href to something like `#ui-tabs1`, is there a way to override this behaviour without breaking tabs, basically I want to pass my own descriptive names e.g. `#api` instead of `#ui-tabs1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check out the [`idPrefix`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-idPrefix) option notes:

> If the remote tab, its anchor element that is, has no title attribute
>   to generate an id from, an id/fragment identifier is created from this
>   prefix and a unique id

This leads me to believe you can either specify a `title`attribute on each link to specify the fragment (probably what you're looking for), or if applicable, you can specify a common prefix for each fragment.